# Run script on login gnome

Tags: bash, shell, startup, gnome, autostart

I just installed the Cairo dock in gnome and would like to hide/remove the standard dash in gnome. I followed the instructions on the Cairo website ([here](http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Cairo-Dock%20and%20Gnome-Shell&lang=en#1-%20Remove%20the%20dash)). If i run the code in the terminal it works but i would like to run it on startup:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview._dash.actor.hide();'
```

I created a gedit file with this code in `~/Desktop` and set execute permissions. I used the  startup application (`gnome-session-properties`) to run it on startup but i doesn't work. Next thing i tried was to add `bash` in front of the path to the script in the startup application GUI. No succes either. I also tried to write a shell script with nano ([as explained here](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php)):

```
#!/bin/bash
#hide gnome dash

dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview._dash.actor.hide();'
```

Saved the script in `~/Desktop` and add it in the startup application GUI. Didn't work. I also saved the script in `~/.config/autostart` but that failed as well. On startup the dash is still there.

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to learn so please be clear :)

Comment: anyone that can help out? much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A shell script named .gnomerc in your home directory is automatically sourced each time you log in to a GNOME session. You can put arbitrary commands in there; environment variables that you set in this script will be seen by any program that you run in your session.

Note that the session does not start until the .gnomerc script is finished; therefore, if you want to autostart some long-running program, you need to append & to the program invocation, in order to detach it from the running shell.